# Program runs from inside Visual Studio 2022 but not outside

Tags: c++, c++20

I have created a simple C++ program and tested it throughout development.
It works perfectly when I press Ctrl + F5 (run without debugging) but when I execute the .exe file the solution builds directly it fails to open the process.
I have no clue how this is possible because both me and Visual Studio are executing the same file.

This is my code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <ranges>
#include <algorithm>
#include <memory>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <TlHelp32.h>
#include <filesystem>

#include "WindowsService.h"

namespace fs = std::filesystem;

constexpr std::wstring_view PROCESS_NAME = L"audiodg.exe";

DWORD getAudiodgPID() {
    HANDLE snapshot = ::CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
    if (snapshot == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        std::cerr << "Error creating process snapshot: " << ::GetLastError() << std::endl;
        return 0x0;
    }

    PROCESSENTRY32 process_entry;
    process_entry.dwSize = sizeof(process_entry);
    BOOL result = ::Process32First(snapshot, &process_entry);
    while (result && std::wstring_view(process_entry.szExeFile) != PROCESS_NAME) {
        result = ::Process32Next(snapshot, &process_entry);
    }
    if (!result) {
        std::cerr << "Could not find process for audiodg.exe" << std::endl;
        return 0x0;
    }

    return process_entry.th32ProcessID;
}

void setAffinity(DWORD PID, DWORD_PTR mask) {
    HANDLE handle = ::OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, PID);
    if (!handle) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to open process for PID " << PID << std::endl;
        return;
    }
    if (::SetProcessAffinityMask(handle, mask) == 0) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to set affinity mask to handle: " << ::GetLastError() << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    std::cout << "CPU affinity set\n";
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Initializing...\n";

    wchar_t buffer[MAX_PATH];
    GetModuleFileName(NULL, buffer, MAX_PATH);
    std::wcout << "Process name: " << buffer << std::endl;

    fs::path source = buffer;
    fs::path destination = "C:/temp/audiodgfix.exe";

    try {
        fs::copy(source, destination, fs::copy_options::overwrite_existing);
    }
    catch (const fs::filesystem_error& ex) {
        std::cout << "Error copying itself: " << ex.what() << std::endl;
    }

    // These lines can be disconsidered as they are not part of the problem as I have already removed these and the behavior is the same
    /*WindowsService windowsService;
    windowsService.RegisterService(L"audiodgafffixer", L"Audio Affinity Fixer", L"Fixes Windows' audiodg.exe process to have affinity with just CPU 2 to fix Discord having glitchy audio");*/

    DWORD processHandle = getAudiodgPID();
    if (processHandle == 0x0) return 1;
    setAffinity(processHandle, 0b100);
    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Running inside the IDE with Ctrl + F5 executes everything perfectly but running the EXE file manually in the same folder returns "Failed to open process for PID 4764"
The file already has UAC requireAdministrator so it's not a permission issue afaik.

I tried checking if me and Visual Studio were executing the same file, we are.
I haven't moved the .exe file from the build output dir and there are no external DLLs or libraries being used.

**SOLUTION** The issue lies in the fact that even with admin privileges the user doesn't have permission to alter the audiodg.exe process. Using command prompt works because it is interpreted as the account Administrator. I made a simple setup to change the permissions before setting up the file and the service up, changing the permissions to allow the local user to make changes to it.

Comment: Adding to this, the program runs fine when executed directly from Command Prompt. Using .\AudioAffinityFixer.exe works perfectly but executing the file does not. Both are with administrator privileges.

Comment: *but running the EXE file manually* -- But then you say -- *the program runs fine when executed directly from Command Prompt* -- Isn't running from the command prompt "manual"?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie yes it is technically manually but I do think it is very clear I mean running the file by double-clicking it on Windows Explorer/Run as Administrator on Windows Explorer's context menu.

Comment: Could it be due to a different `CWD` (Current Working Directory)?

Comment: *but I do think it is very clear I mean running the file by double-clicking it* -- Believe it or not, that is far from being "manual".  You have another application showing the name of the executable in a fancy GUI, then you are using the mouse to start the program -- there are too many variables involved.  Compare that to going directly to the command line, typing in the name, hitting enter -- this has been the way to run command programs since probably the invention of the computer terminal and keyboard.

Comment: @JesperJuhl the directory is the same. I made the program output its process path and full name to make sure of that.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie The program has no UI as you can see by the code. Executing the program through Windows Explorer initiates a console as it's a console application. The issue here seems to be UAC. I'm considering changing to the Administrator account of Windows to check if it's my user that doesn't have access to the audiodg.exe process. That would explain why console with admin can execute it but user with admin rights can't. Probably the user itself doesn't have clearance to mess with audiodg.exe. This is my assumption and I will test it later today as soon as I get home.

Comment: @Zeki I know it may be a convenience for the lazy user, but even I wouldn't expect a command-line program, doesn't matter what it does, to "behave correctly" when double-clicked inside of Windows Explorer.   Command-line programs are designed to be run by a knowledgable user from the command-line.  I can't count how many times I've created command-line programs, and the (lazy) user wants to double-click on the name in Explorer (or some other app), instead of running it as designed.  Then to accomodate that user, you end up jumping through hoops to get the program to work in Explorer.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie sadly I did have to come up with a solution because the end user should have this as a service running on startup and Windows still didn't have permission even when being executed by a service. All I had to do is make a setup that would change the user permissions to the audiodg.exe file and process to allow it to be modified by the local user and not only the Administrator account itself. It now works perfectly.

Comment: What for do you need this system("pause") at the end? How the behavior would change if you replace it with _getch() ?

Comment: I don't understand what is the purpose of your question

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're running the correct version of the program. Sometimes, Visual Studio might create multiple versions of the same program, so make sure you're running the correct one.
Use a debugging tool to help you figure out where the program is failing. You can use a tool like Visual Studio's debugger to step through the program line-by-line and see where it's breaking.

Comment: There aren't multiple versions and VS overwrites the output every time. Even then I deleted all the compiler output folders and rebuilt the solution clean, same results. I have debugged already and the output in console is part of the debugging process I went through. When executing the EXE via Explorer the user seems to not have the rights to mess with the target process even though UAC is set to requireAdministrator